# Angular filtering table results not working properly

Tags: angular

I have a table in Angular which i'm filtering. In `ngOnInit` I fetch the data and save it to a local variables in order to not make another call for the DB in order to get the data.

Here's the code of the search method:

```
search() {
    if (this.searched.length > 0) {
      this.history = this.history.filter(res => {
        return res.DestinationCompany.match(this.searched) || res.OriginCompany.match(this.searched) || res.AuctionSerialNumber.match(this.searched) || res.AuctionSerialNumber.match(this.searched);
      })
    } else {
      this.history = this.historyOrigin;
    }
  }
```

The problem is that when I'm deleting a character the results doesn't update even if they can show more results. For example if I'm searching the expression '7' i get 5 results, if I'm searching the expression '71' iIget 1 result but if now I'm searching '7' again I get 1 result also until I delete all the characters and get back the full results.

How to get more results when i'm deleting a character

Comment: I've posted the relevant code in the question, and have fixed a big number of typos, missing capitalization, etc. in your post. Next time, do that **yourself** before posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the search filter, you filter the data that has already been filtered by the previous search.

Don't do that. Keep a copy of the original, complete list of data, and each time you search, created a filtered copy of that original list, stored in a **different** variable.

In short, replace

```
this.history = this.history.filter(...)
```

by

```
this.history = this.historyOrigin.filter(...)
```